# Extracting directory name from an absolute path using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to split this line

```
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh
```

to

```
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin
```

using `sed` or `awk` scripts? Could you help on this?

Comment: What's the context? Is that in a file? Do you have more than one occurrence? Do you... ?

Comment: sed and awk are overkill for this, shells have utilities for this directly.

Comment: if you're using bash: why not use `dirname` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be command **dirname** is what you searching for?

```
dirname /home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh
```

Or if you want sed, so see my solution:

```
echo /home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
```

Comment: `sed`-based solution has a problem with path containing only base name. `dirname` returns `.` in that case.

Answer (score 15):

dirname

```
kent$  dirname "/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh"
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin
```

sed

```
kent$  echo "/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh"|sed 's#/[^/]*$##'
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin
```

grep

```
kent$  echo "/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh"|grep  -oP '^/.*(?=/)'
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin
```

awk

```
kent$  echo "/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh"|awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{print $1}'
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin
```

Comment: In all these alternatives to `dirname` there is a problem with paths containing only basename. `dirname` gives `.` in that case. `grep` version returns an empty string and others works as `basename`

Comment: The `awk` call will also fail on cases like `foo/bar/`

Answer (score 4):

For most platforms and Unix/Linux shells now available `dirname`:

```
dirname /home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh
```

Using of `dirname` is the simpliest way, but it is not recommended for cross platform scripting for example in the last version of `autoconf` documentation http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Limitations-of-Usual-Tools.html#Limitations-of-Usual-Tools .

So my full featured version of `sed`-based alternative for `dirname`:

```
str="/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh"
echo "$str" | sed -n -e '1p' | sed  -e 's#//*#/#g' -e 's#\(.\)/$#\1#' -e 's#^[^/]*$#.#' -e 's#\(.\)/[^/]*$#\1#' -
```

**Examples:**

It works like `dirname`:

- For path like `/aa/bb/cc` it will print `/aa/bb`
- For path like `/aa/bb` it will print `/aa`
- For path like `/aa/bb/` it will print `/aa` too.
- For path like `/aa/` it will print `/aa`
- For path like `/` it will print `/`
- For path like `aa` it will print `.`
- For path like `aa/` it will print `.`

**That is:**

- It works correct with trailing `/`
- It works correct with paths that contains only base name like `aa` and `aa/`
- It works correct with paths starting with `/` and the path `/` itself.
- It works correct with any `$str` if it contains `\n` at the end or not, even with many `\n`
- It uses cross platform sed command
- It changes all combinations of `/` (`//` `///`) to `/`
- It can't work correct with paths containing newlines and characters invalid for current locale.

**Note**
Alternative for `basename` may be useful:

```
echo "$str" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' -
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm the only one who's upvoted this over three years. Hats off for this amazing sed one-liner. I wrote a lengthier version and added compatibility tests against `dirname` and this one-line (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68403443/758334). The oneliner's only difference with `dirname` is that it strips the extra leading slashes (ex "//a/b" -> "/a"), but may or may not be what you want in some situations. Still, those are some impressive sed ninja skills.

Answer (score 3):

This code with **awk** will work perfectly as same as **dirname**, I guess.

It's so simple and has very low cost to work. Good luck.

***Code***

```
$ foo=/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java
$ echo "$foo" | awk -F "/*[^/]*/*$" '
{ print ($1 == "" ? (substr($0, 1, 1) == "/" ? "/" : ".") : $1); }'
```

***Result***

`/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin`

***Test***

- `foo=/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java` -> `/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin`
- `foo=/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/` -> `/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71`
- `foo=/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin` -> `/app/java/jdk1.7.0_71`
- `foo=/app/` -> `/`
- `foo=/app` -> `/`
- `foo=fighters/` -> `.`

***More***

If you're not available such awk delimiter, try it this way.

```
$ echo $foo | awk '{
 dirname = gensub("/*[^/]*/*$", "", "", $0);
 print (dirname == "" ? (substr($0, 1, 1) == "/" ? "/" : ".") : dirname);
 }'
```

Comment: Just fails on a case like `/foo/////bar` with multiple slashes. A tweak would be: `awk -F "/?[^/]*/?$" '{gsub("/+","/"); print ($1==""?(substr($0, 1, 1)=="/"?"/":".") : $1); }'`

Comment: @kvantour  Nice advice! but, I think this is better way: `awk -F "/*[^/]*/*$" '{print ($1==""?(substr($0, 1, 1)=="/"?"/":".") : $1); }'` Diffences: `"/?[^/]*/?$" ` -> `"/*[^/]*/*$" ` This covers another fails: `/foo/////bar/////` Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

awk + for :

```
echo "/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh" | awk 'BEGIN{res=""; FS="/";}{ for(i=2;i<=NF-1;i++) res=(res"/"$i);} END{print res}'
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition, to the answer of Kent, an alternative awk solution is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{NF--}1'
```

which has the same sickness as the one presented by Kent. The following, somewhat longer Awk corrects all the flaws:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{gsub("/+","/")}
     {s=$0~/^\//;NF-=$NF?1:2;$0=$0?$0:(s?"/":".")};1' <file>
```

The following table shows the difference:

```
| path       | dirname | awk full | awk short |
|------------+---------+----------+-----------|
| .          | .       | .        |           |
| /          | /       | /        |           |
| foo        | .       | .        |           |
| foo/       | .       | .        | foo       |
| foo/bar    | foo     | foo      | foo       |
| foo/bar/   | foo     | foo      | foo/bar   |
| /foo       | /       | /        |           |
| /foo/      | /       | /        | /foo      |
| /foo/bar   | /foo    | /foo     | /foo      |
| /foo/bar/  | /foo    | /foo     | /foo/bar  |
| /foo///bar | /foo    | /foo     | /foo//    |
```

**note:** `dirname` is the real way to go, unless you have to process masses of them stored in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always amazed at how clever some one-liners are. In my case, I went for readability, so here's my implementation. It's a vanilla Bourne shell script with a dependency on sed and grep that mimics `dirname`.

```sh
strip_trailing_slashes() {
  printf "$1" | sed 's/[/]*$//'
}

# If empty arg, return .
# If nothing but slashes, return /
# If no slashes after stripping all trailing slashes, return .
# Otherwise, return everything up until last path component
dirname() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then printf '.'; return; fi
  if ! $(printf "$1" | grep -q '[^/]'); then printf '/'; return; fi

  local s="$(strip_trailing_slashes $1)"
  if ! $(printf "$s" | grep -q '/'); then printf '.'; fi

  printf "$(strip_trailing_slashes $(printf $s | sed 's/[^/]*$//'))"
}
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/4b24415fcd7d1250d8ea3eaa0aea35a0) that includes 44 tests for the following cases -- and also tests against `dirname` for compatibility.

```
Expect '.' for ('""' '.' '.foo' './foo' 'foo' 'foo/' 'foo///' '..' '..foo' '..foo//' '../')
Expect '/' for ('/' '//' '///')
Expect 'a/b' for ('a/b/c' 'a/b/c/' 'a/b/c///')
Expect '/a/b' for ('/a/b/c' '/a/b/c/' '/a/b/c///')
Expect '//a/b' for ('//a/b/c' '//a/b/c//' '/a/b/c')
```

A few points:

1. The [one-liner sed version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692524/758334) by @Роман Коптев is amazing (how can I be the only one who's upvoted?).
2. The only two test failures are due to the oneliner version, but it differs from `dirname`. The oneliner version converts the following "//a/b/c" to "/a/b", which might not be what you want; `dirname` doesn't strip extra leading slashes and returns "//a/b". I chose to make my version compatible with `dirname`. (None of the versions strip extra slashes in the middle separating path components).

Hat's off to @Роман Коптев for the oneliner version!