# bash get dirname from urls.txt

Tags: bash

```
$ cat urls.txt
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/email-inliner.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/email.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/email2-inliner.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/email2.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/AquaTrainingBag.png
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/fitex-ecr7.jpg
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/fitex-ect7.jpg
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/fitex-ecu7.jpg
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/fitex.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/logo.png
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/form.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/fitex/fitex.txt
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/bigsale.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/logo.png
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/bigsale.png
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/bigsale-shop.html
/var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/bigsale.txt
```

Can anyone help me to get `dirname` for this?

`dirname /var/www/example.com.com/upload/email/sss.png` works fine, but what about a list of URLs?

Is it possible to achieve this without the use of any form of a loop (`for` or `while`). As the number of URLs can be more than several tens of millions. The best way would be with the help of redirection (tee) to a file

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me, at least). Do you want the `dirname` for each file? `dirname` of all files? Please be specific, coherent and accurate in your description.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show exact required output from one of the inputs. Also show your best attempt to solve the problem.StackOverflow is dedicated to helping people solve their coding skills problems, but not to do their work for them. Good luck.

Comment: Technically, those aren't URLs; they are file paths (they're missing the protocol). A crucial difference is that a file path can contain any valid character (other than the null byte), while a URL is more restricted. If those are really "protocol-less" URLs, `xargs -L 1 dirname < urls.txt` should suffice.

Comment: i need get dirname for pathes in txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always when it boils down to things like this, Awk comes to the rescue:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{NF--}1' <file>
```

Be aware that this is an extremely simplified version of `dirname` and does not have the complete identical implementation as `dirname`, but it will work for most cases. A correct version, which covers all cases is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{gsub("/+","/")}
     {s=$0~/^\//;NF-=$NF?1:2;$0=$0?$0:(s?"/":".")};1' <file>
```

The following table shows the difference:

```
| path       | dirname | awk full | awk short |
|------------+---------+----------+-----------|
| .          | .       | .        |           |
| /          | /       | /        |           |
| foo        | .       | .        |           |
| foo/       | .       | .        | foo       |
| foo/bar    | foo     | foo      | foo       |
| foo/bar/   | foo     | foo      | foo/bar   |
| /foo       | /       | /        |           |
| /foo/      | /       | /        | /foo      |
| /foo/bar   | /foo    | /foo     | /foo      |
| /foo/bar/  | /foo    | /foo     | /foo/bar  |
| /foo///bar | /foo    | /foo     | /foo//    |
```

**note:** various alternative solutions can be found in [Extracting directory name from an absolute path using sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560295/extracting-directory-name-from-an-absolute-path-using-sed-or-awk). The solutions of [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560723/8344060) will all work, the solution of [Solid Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059831/8344060) just needs a tiny tweak to fix the multiple slashes (and misses upvotes!)