# Strip last field

Tags: awk

My script will be receiving various lengths of input and I want to strip the last field separated by a "/". An example of the input I will be dealing with is.

```
this/that/and/more
```

But the issue I am running into is that the length of the input will vary like so:

```
this/that/maybe/more/and/more
or/even/this/could/be/it/and/maybe/more
short/more
```

In any case, the expected output should be the whole string minus the last "/more".

**Note:** The word "more" will not be a constant these are arbitrary examples.

**Example input:**

```
this/that/and/more
this/that/maybe/more/and/more
```

**Expected output:**

```
this/that/and
this/that/maybe/more/and
```

What I know works for a string you know the length of would be

```
cut -d'/' -f[x]
```

With what I need is a '/' delimited AWK command I'm assuming like:

```
awk '{$NF=""; print $0}'
```

Comment: Very much related too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560295/extracting-directory-name-from-an-absolute-path-using-sed-or-awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk as requested:

```
$ awk '{sub("/[^/]*$","")} 1' file
this/that/maybe/more/and
or/even/this/could/be/it/and/maybe
short
```

but this is the type of job sed is best suited for:

```
$ sed 's:/[^/]*$::' file
this/that/maybe/more/and
or/even/this/could/be/it/and/maybe
short
```

The above were run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
this/that/maybe/more/and/more
or/even/this/could/be/it/and/maybe/more
short/more
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you have the input in your script, bash's Shell Parameter Expansion may be convenient:

```
$ s1=this/that/maybe/more/and/more
$ s2=or/even/this/could/be/it/and/maybe/more
$ s3=short/more

$ echo ${s1%/*}
this/that/maybe/more/and

$ echo ${s2%/*}
or/even/this/could/be/it/and/maybe

$ echo ${s3%/*}
short
```

(Lots of additional info on parameter expansion at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks, @DavidC.Rankin, completely right. Corrected.

Comment: This works well and i appreciate it but all i can do is up vote you because i asked for awk. But this is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you could create a loop that removes the last character in the input string if it is not a slash through each iteration. Then, when the loop finds a slash character, exit the loop then remove the final character (which is supposed to be a slash).

Pseudo-code:

```
while (lastCharacter != '/') {
    removeLastCharacter();
}
removeLastCharacter();    # removes the slash
```

(Sorry, it's been a while since I wrote a bash script.)

Comment: Hmm..., it kinda leaves me wondering where `removeLastCharacter()` comes from and more importantly what it contains. Moreover, where does `lastCharacter` come from? Maybe you want to rethink the example using `var` as the variable holding the string to be trimmed and then look at the *parameter expansions* `${var:0: -1}` (note the space) or `${var:0:(-1)}` (no space) for removing the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` alternative using fields instead of regexs

```
awk -F/ '{printf "%s", $1; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf "/%s", $i; printf "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative shell solution:

```
while read -r path; do dirname "$path"; done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing `NF` store the number of fields of the current record

```bash
$ awk -F/ '{print NF, $NF}' <<< "a/b/c/d/e"
5 e
```

but `NF` can actually be written to:

```bash
$ awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '{NF=NF-1; print NF; print $NF; print $0}' <<< "a/b/c/d/e"
4
d
a/b/c/d
```

I think it make an elegant solution (tested with `mawk` and `gawk`).